# EV Charging Efficiency

Tags: charging, electric-vehicle

On most (all?) EVs there is a "sweet spot" charging from 10 or 20 percent up to around 80 percent where the battery is accepting charge at a relatively high and even rate. Then somewhere around 80 percent the rate of charge starts to taper off. On our Niro EV the time to charge from 80 to 100 percent is around as long as the time to charge from 20 to 80 percent.

So, what I'm wondering is, is the slowing the rate of charge accompanied by a reduction in the "return on investment?" Do I have to put more energy into the charging system to go, say, from 80 to 90 percent than to go from 70 to 80 percent?

Comment: According to searches, your Niro ev uses a 64.8 kWh nickel cobalt manganese (NCM) battery from CATL (China), not a lithium ion type. This makes charging rates different from Li-ion because of the battery chemistry dictating efficient charging rates, Correct me if I'm wrong. With different battery chemistries, charging rates cannot be compared between two different batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is indeed a "sweet spot" for charging LiIon-type batteries.

The problem is that as the battery approaches full charge, more of the input energy turns into heat in the battery.  This causes two issues:

1. More heat raises the cell resistance which causes more heat.  This is why auto manufacturers build in systems to monitor this very closely.  They (obviously) want to avoid a runaway heat condition which can lead to unpleasant results.
2. As the battery approaches full charge, there are fewer and fewer charge carriers in the battery available to be put back into their original places.  So the charging process becomes less and less efficient.  This is very akin to why a vacuum pump takes longer and longer to reduce the pressure by a given unit as it gets closer to 0.  There are simply fewer and fewer air molecules around for it to pump out.

On many EVs, the "normal" charge is not to 100% since that is both inefficient and hard on battery life.  Most offer a setting to charge to 100% on those occasions where you know you're going to be using max range the next time you drive it.

Answer (score 0):

This comes up in a couple of different ways.

First, if you are *tapering* the charge toward the end, this will be much more efficient than forcing a specific charge rate.  EV batteries (really, all) prefer a slowing-down taper charge near the end.

**And home AC level 2 charging is pretty much a "trickle charge" to an enormous EV battery**. The more sensible the level 2 charging, the better this is.  Imagine if you slowed down the charge rate on your phone so it took 20 hours to charge, obviously that would be very gentle on the battery.  That is a good metaphor of level 2 charging on an EV.

### Big is not a virtue

Now, many people get a serious case of "the bigs" when installing level 2 charging. They don't bother thinking about their need and just install the biggest option possible.  Often in gross disregard of what is safe or legal to add to their already-heavily-loaded electric service!

[Many of us preach sanity and restraint](https://youtu.be/Iyp_X3mwE1w?t=1695), pointing out that even a 20A/240V circuit giving 3840W charging is more than enough for almost every use, and will fit in the reserve headroom of most houses.

For "But Sometimes" moments, there is **DC fast charging** - do this *while low* on the way home, and then charge the last hundred or so miles at home. That way the DC fast charge happens in the middle of battery range, where it performs best, and your level 2 charge provides the taper/finish charge it is well-sized for.

Obviously a 3840W "20 amp circuit" charge rate will be gentler to the battery and charge marginally more efficiently than a 11,520 watt "60 amp" charge rate.

### But there are parasitic loads too.

The only monkey-wrench in this is battery conditioning and cooling.

In warmer temperatures, the car may need to run the battery cooling system (coolant loop) to keep the batteries cool during charging.  This 'battery cooling' burden gets worse the faster the charge rate, so slow charging will be more efficient.

Assuming the EV is able to "throttle" the cooling rate!  If it runs the cooling system wide-open at any charge rate, then the cooling burden is equal for every charge rate, and that hurts the efficiency of slower charging.

At cold temperatures, the EV charger must "pre-heat" the battery to a charge-safe temperature before it can start charging.  That means using wall energy to run the battery cooling system "backwards" with resistive heating or a heat pump to warm the battery above freezing. **This initial warm-up will cost exactly the same regardless of charge rate**.  However, a too-slow too-efficient charge may not warm the battery enough, and may require more supplemental heating during charge.